# Need help applying the root test for: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, or not... I've got an answer but it doesn't look right to me.

> Given the following series, determine if it is convergent or divergent using the root or ratio test. If the test is inconclusive, use another test.
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right)^n$$

Here's my step by step process. Maybe I left something out.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right)^n\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right)$$
$$=-2$$

But, even though $-2<1$, I'm very hesitant to claim that the series is convergent. I somehow feel like the answer should be positive, and I don't know if I should take the absolute value of the limit and say that the series is divergent.

Comment: The essence of the Root Test is to compare the _limit_ of the general term of the infinite series to the general term of a geometric series.  Since we know that  $ \ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} a \cdot r^n \ $ converges for $ \ | r | < 1 \ $ and diverges for $ \ | r | > 1 \ $ , it is reasonable that an infinite series  $ \ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^n \ $ should converge for $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} | a_n | < 1 \ $ and diverge where that limit of absolute value exceeds 1 .  For your series, the "corresponding" geometric series is $ \ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (-2)^n \ $ , which surely diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You take the limit of the absolute value of the general term $\;\sqrt[\large n]{|a_n|}$, and after taking the $n$th root, what remains is still the absolute value of the nth root. Taking the limit of the absolute value of the nth root, in your case, will give you $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right)^n\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}\;=\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2}{e^{-8n}-1}\right| = 2$$

Hence, in your case, the series will indeed by divergent.

Comment: I thought the abs bars vanished after I took the n'th root of the whole thing...

Comment: No, not at all. It remains. The $nth$ root doesn't change the fact that what remains is absolute value of the "rooted" expression.

Comment: Yes, agent154: you can see the limit of the absolute value as being the absolute value of the limit.

Comment: I've updated my question to show my thought process... maybe you could point out where I missed something?

Comment: The first step after taking the nth root is mistaken: we need to **keep** the absolute value intact after taking the nth root. That's crucial when you test for absolute convergence, for example, of an alternating series.

Comment: Thanks as always. I asked my prof about this in class one day, asking if once we use the absolute value and found that there was no alternating terms, could we drop the bars? I guess not.

Comment: You're welcome, agent154.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice written and discourse +1

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need toconsider $|u_n|$ under the $$\sqrt[n]{...}$$ because the test tells us to do $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|u_n|}$$ And that's why you would find the series divergent.

Comment: Here's another question - is $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=|\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n|$? Otherwise I have no idea how things change.

Comment: @agent154: The function $|...|$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Be careful. Certainly it can happen that $\lim |a_n|$ exists and $\lim a_n$ does not!

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes Prof. I just noted this matter for this series. Of course $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ have a notable behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason we shouldn't drop the absolute value at first is this:
$$|z^n|=|z||z...z|=|z||z||z...z|=|z|^n$$ for all z complex